# selenium 3 firefox uses wrong media query

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, testing, geckodriver

We are upgrading our testing tools from Selenium 2.53 to the newest (3.11.0) Selenium with Selenium-grid-3. We are using Jenkins to run Scenarios through grid on slave machines on Chrome and Firefox.
Geckodriver for Firefox does not support Firefox V<=47, therefore we must upgrade Mozilla browser as well to the newest version (59.0.2).

Running test cases on Chrome is fine. On the other hand running test cases on Firefox is absolutely not fine.

The problem is that Firefox somehow uses different media query which means that some element is not visible on the page, therefore Selenium for example can not click on it (Browser resolution is fullHD but uses @media screen and (max-width: 750px) all the time).

We tested the same test case on Selenium 2.53 and Firefox 47.0.2 and that was fine, everything went well (and as I mentioned It is okay on Chrome as well).

Does anybody know any solution for this problem? Thank you

UPDATE:

Here is the gherkin:

```
When I open Irista
Then Irista 'Homepage' is loaded

When I sign in to irista with 'xxx' username and 'xxx' password
Then Irista 'Timeline' is loaded

When I open the hosturl with custom ending '/fivehundred'
Then the 'error_500_page' is loaded
And the 'irista main logo' element is 'visible'
```

When it checks the visibility of the main logo it fails, because on 750px width the logo's display is none.

Here you can see the page with the logo in the top left corner of the screen:
[Page with logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrSeD.png)

The page without the logo:
[Page without logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QVSc.jpg)

And as you can see, it uses width: 750px query
[Page without logo with settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avh2u.png)

The problem:

```
    org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for com.oce.common.autotest.util.PageUtilBy$$Lambda$129/649053158@7969e045 (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval) Build info: version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50', time: '2018-02-07T22:25:02.294Z' System info: host: 'OSZ-WS00044', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.13.0-38-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_151' 
Driver info: org.jbehave.web.selenium.RemoteWebDriverProvider$ScreenshootingRemoteWebDriver Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 58.0.2, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 15628, moz:profile: C:\Users\osz-brtest01\AppDa..., moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, webdriver.remote.sessionid: 9ed1c654-d052-4a5b-b557-14a...} Session ID: 9ed1c654-d052-4a5b-b557-14a737f7216d
```

Comment: Update the question with code trials, relevant HTML and error stack trace please.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I added update on the question!

Comment: You missed the error traces. Your quote "running test cases on Firefox is absolutely not fine." Post the logs where it is not fine.

Comment: Added the error traces, bit It won't help. The problem is that because on low media query the element is not visible (display: none;), therefore the step (assert) won't return true.